# Azure Resource Provider concepts

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace, azure-store

I try to write my own [Resource Provider](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-provider-sdk) to create a new Add-On to Azure MarketPlace, but I have got some not clear concepts about the Provider.

If the user wants to get details on a Resource, Azure will do a GET for that particular resource.

```
<provisioning_endpoint>/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/cloudservices/<cloud_service_name>/resources/<resource_type>/<resourceName>
```

I know that I can set up the Resource Type at the Publisher Portal under application services//Resource Provider. But what about the Resorce? If I want to create a new service (for example SendGrid did) I don't want to make a Virtual Machine or an Add-on, I want to create e.x. a Subscription in my Site. Azure will do a GET request to my provider and that request will include the name of the resource. But where/how can I set up the name of the Resource?

I think the Resource is the string that the user can enter in the Portal from
"Purchase from Marketplace

I read that Resources are nested under a named entity called a CloudService. Where can I set the name of the CloudService? What could be a possible name of the CloudService in my case? Or I missunderstand the whole working of the Resource Provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<provisioning_endpoint>/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/cloudservices/<cloud_service_name>/resources/<resource_type>/<resourceName>
```

Azure will send you requests to your end point URL. When you split the URL into chunks you will get something like:

```
[1] => addon
[2] => azure
[3] => resources
[4] => subscriptions
[5] => 6163ffa8-4b05-4bc3-8c45-5656d279c87c
[6] => cloudservices
[7] => Azure-Stores-H4PFJULZHK3OKNFGJZTK5P3XGRVORLB7ZDAZVKEBLZLUVIGNJKGA-West-US
[8] => resources
[9] => marketing2-6460E175-C5B7-4571-9189-7A2630A4CE32
[10] => ContosoAPPSTAGED3
```

So looking at the line above from the doc and the received URL chunks the resourceName in this case is ContosoAPPSTAGED3